# jQuery check if element has css attribute

Tags: jquery, attributes

I need to know when I click on an element if this element has a CSS attribute. I am thinking of something like this, but it does not work:

```
if ($('#element').attr("text-shadow")) {
    alert ('i Have')
}
else {
    alert ('i dont')
}
```

Any tips on this one?
Thanx

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
if( $('#element').css('text-shadow') != null )  { 
    /*success*/ 
} 
else { 
    /*does not have*/ 
}
```

Comment: for some reason this does not work. There must be something wrong with my code.

Comment: It works for me with 1.4.2. Which version of jQuery are you using. Which browser? Can you provide a sample .html page and host it somewhere so I can debug the issue and see what's going on?

Comment: @Bears: Maybe, but in this specific instance, the two should be equivalent, and your solution is an extra non-compressable byte :P.

Comment: Sorry it was a browser thing. i restart it and works now.
Thanx.

Comment: Would this work if I needed to check a certain attribute's current value (example >> left: 0)?

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to test 'width' style property. Behavior in Firefox is slightly differ from other browsers.

```
if (jQuery(value).css('width') == '0px') { // width not set
    jQuery(value).css('width', '320px');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this instead:

```
if($('#element').css('text-shadow') == null) ...
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I opened this question before any answers had been posted then stepped away from my desk for a moment. My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

`$('#element').css("text-shadow")`

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
if ($('#element')[0].style.text-shadow != '') {
    alert ('i Have')
}
else {
    alert ('i dont')
}
```